# when I gave the space between text and underline . the length of text and underline are not equal why?

Tags: css

I wanted space between text and underline  and I did but problem is that LENGTH OF TEXT AND UNDERLINE are not equal why? Please help

```
a { /*Here is My code @Smart*/ 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:red; 
  position:relative; 
  transition: all .2s ease-in 
 } 
a:hover { 
 position:relative; 
 border-bottom:4px solid red; 
 }
```

Comment: can you add your code here ?

Comment: a {                                             /*Here is My code @Smart*/
 text-decoration:none;
color:red;
position:relative;
transition: all .2s ease-in
}
 a:hover {
position:relative;
  border-bottom:4px solid red;
}

Comment: please give fiddle or snippet for it..

Comment: Please add your html code too.

Comment: /* here is my html code @Smart */<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled"><li class="menu-home menu-item-553"><a href="http://localhost/sigmaccp/">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-shop current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-98"><a href="http://localhost/sigmaccp/index.php/shop/">Shop</a></li>
<li class="menu-customers menu-item-648"><a href="http://localhost/sigmaccp/index.php/customers-2/">Customers</a></li>
<li class="menu-faq menu-item-548"><a href="http://localhost/sigmaccp/index.php/faq-2/">FAQ</a></li>

</ul>

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```css
a{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
a:hover:after  {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ec6713;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

output

[image]

Comment: I need some space between text and underline

Comment: Check it the length of text and length of underline are not equal. Please correct it

Comment: Ya I checked your updated answer  it's same as I have,Please check length of text and underline

Comment: the length of text and underline is same, refer to attached img in updated answer

Comment: still I have problem in my website loaded in wordpress